# Multi User Editing

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, ado.net, concurrency

I have a system where I would like to show a warning to a user if there try and edit a record that is currently been edited. If this is the case the user will not be able to save the record but only view it.

I have an idea of using some kind of class to monitor the activity of records  been edited etc but this seams a little over kill. ***My other concern is that what if the browser crashes or there shut their computer down on how this will effect the state of the page.***

Another thought was to use last updated time stamp but this also looks a no go because the way records are been updated.

Has anyone got any thoughts or resources on how I could implement something like this. No code is necessary.

based on the comments I have added these additional details.
database is SQL server 2008
asp.net 3.5
one record could be many parts of the database for instance, the booking table session table and a row in the interrupter table.

the user will look at a list of sessions that need booking select a booking and fill out a booking form to make the booking. Want to stop is someone else trying to do the same booking at the same time or while someone else is doing the booking.

Comment: I would recomment to replace the `.NET`-tag(or one of C#/VB.NET) with `ASP.NET`. Have a look at MSDN for [optimistic/pessimistic concurrency in ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz.aspx).

Comment: what architecture and technology you use? APS.NET + DB ? WPF + DB? No DB? Explain better, please. What is a "record" actually. ?

Comment: thanks for the link will have a read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esentially I maintain an `Edit` (lookup) table in the SQL database comprising 4 fields `UserID, Action, EntityID and Datestamp` and link that to each associated page and editable item.

So, for example if the user is on the edit Foo webpage and clicks the `edit` link, the program will perform a lookup of the `Edit` table and if nobody else is editing a record does an insert, i.e: `4, 'Edit Foo', 123, GETUTCDATE()` where 123 is the ID of the `Foo` being edited.

There are many further functions to the process, for example, if a user is in edit mode for a length of time the record automatically removed from the table and the item becomes editable again.

However, the solution works very well for us in a high use environment. I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at MSDN for [optimistic/pessimistic concurrency in ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz.aspx).

> **Pessimistic concurrency** involves locking rows at the data source to
> prevent other users from modifying data in a way that affects the
> current user. In a pessimistic model, when a user performs an action
> that causes a lock to be applied, other users cannot perform actions
> that would conflict with the lock until the lock owner releases it.
> This model is primarily used in environments where there is heavy
> contention for data, so that the cost of protecting data with locks is
> less than the cost of rolling back transactions if concurrency
> conflicts occur.
>
> By contrast, users who use **optimistic concurrency** do not lock a row
> when reading it. When a user wants to update a row, the application
> must determine whether another user has changed the row since it was
> read. Optimistic concurrency is generally used in environments with a
> low contention for data. Optimistic concurrency improves performance
> because no locking of records is required, and locking of records
> requires additional server resources. Also, in order to maintain
> record locks, a persistent connection to the database server is
> required. Because this is not the case in an optimistic concurrency
> model, connections to the server are free to serve a larger number of
> clients in less time.
>
> In an optimistic concurrency model, a violation is considered to have
> occurred if, after a user receives a value from the database, another
> user modifies the value before the first user has attempted to modify
> it.
>
> **Testing for Optimistic Concurrency Violations**
> There are several techniques for testing for an optimistic concurrency
> violation. One involves including a timestamp column in the table.
> Databases commonly provide timestamp functionality that can be used to
> identify the date and time when the record was last updated. Using
> this technique, a timestamp column is included in the table
> definition. Whenever the record is updated, the timestamp is updated
> to reflect the current date and time. In a test for optimistic
> concurrency violations, the timestamp column is returned with any
> query of the contents of the table. When an update is attempted, the
> timestamp value in the database is compared to the original timestamp
> value contained in the modified row. If they match, the update is
> performed and the timestamp column is updated with the current time to
> reflect the update. If they do not match, an optimistic concurrency
> violation has occurred.
>
> Another technique for testing for an optimistic concurrency violation
> is to verify that all the original column values in a row still match
> those found in the database .....